# Why don't Input.MouseButtonDown and OnPointerClicked Fire in the Same Frame?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to synchronize some user input for my Unity game which requires my GameManager to detect a user click (via `OnMouseButtonDown(0)`) the same time a Gameobject in the scene receives a click (via `OnPointerClick`).

However, after logging the frame count of each input, I discovered they diverge quite a bit such as 50 frames. I have tested both input event listeners using a single component, and confirmed that the frame count of user input is not consistent. I haven't been able to find much in the forums about this issue. I was thinking implementing OnPointerClick in my GameManager file to fix this issue, but since I would like to detect clicks throughout the scene, I don't see how this would be practical since a scene-wide collider would be needed to detect clicks. Also, a scene-wide collider may interfere with other colliders I have set up.

Sorry for the long-winded explanation, but I'm stumped on this one and would appreciate some help.

```
public class CityDetector : EventDetector
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            print("frame count is " + Time.frameCount); // doesn't match below frame count !!!
        }
    }
    public override void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print("frame count is " + Time.frameCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Afaik the pointer clicked event also includes the release of a button so it might be called in the same frame with `GetMouseButtonUp` ... Not sure though

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue here is that you are calling:

```
    public override void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print("frame count is " + Time.frameCount);
    }
```

Outside the Update() function. Since the Time.DeltaTime count the time passed from the last frame, this will desync the two log you are printing.